# Using Keycloak 4.3.0.Final with dropwizard 1.3.1

Tags: jersey, resteasy, dropwizard, keycloak

I am having a problem with integrating keycloak into dropwizard. Keycloak requires the RestEasy client so i had to use the dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.26.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

then I create my httpClient :

```
RxClient<RxCompletionStageInvoker> httpClient = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment)
                .using(configuration.getJerseyClientConfiguration())
                .buildRx(getName(), RxCompletionStageInvoker.class);
```

then i try to use the client, for example :

```
httpClient
.target(path)
.request()
.get();
```

and i get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientRequestContextImpl cannot be cast to org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest
```

when i remove the dependency I get the JercyClient and all httpRequests works find but Keycloak builder fails, when I use RestEasy dependency keyCloak succeeds but all other http requests fails
Have anyone faced this problem before? is there a way to control when to get the resteasy client and when to get the jersey client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use RestEasy dependency but not using the JersyClientBuilder:

```
Client httpClient =  new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
```